# Laravel 11 with MongoDB: Guards not working in Middleware

Tags: laravel, mongodb, laravel-middleware, laravel-11, laravel-guard

I tried using guards for admins but its not working in Middleware in `Laravel 11`. I have connected the `MongoDB` with Laravel 11 for managing its database.

My admin login function looks like below where `Auth::guard('admin')` is working fine:

```
public function login(Request $request){
        if($request->isMethod('post')){
            $data = $request->all();
            if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email'=>$data['email'],'password'=>$data['password']])) {
                //echo "<pre>"; print_r(Auth::guard('admin')->user()); die;
                return redirect('admin/dashboard');
            }else{
                 return redirect()->back()->with('error_message','Invalid Email or Password');
            }
        }
        return view('admin.login');
    }
```

But `Auth::guard('admin')` is not working in Admin Middleware and I am not getting any data. My Admin Middleware file looks like below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Auth;

class Admin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        // echo "<pre>"; print_r(Auth::guard('admin')->user()); die;
        if(!Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
            return redirect('/admin/login');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I have updated the auth.php file located at config\auth.php to set guards for admin to assign session in driver and admins in provider as shown below:

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],
```

Also set providers for admins to assign eloquent in driver and Admin classes in the model.

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => env('AUTH_MODEL', App\Models\User::class),
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],
```

Due to the updates in Laravel 11, I added Admin Middleware in app.php file like below:

```
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->alias(['admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class]);
})
```

My admin routes looks like below:

```
Route::prefix('/admin')->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Admin')->group(function(){
    //All the admin routes will be defined here...
    Route::match(['get','post'],'login',[AdminController::class,'login']);
    Route::group(['middleware'=>['admin']],function(){
        Route::match(['get','post'],'dashboard',[AdminController::class,'dashboard']);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, I have updated `SESSION_DRIVER` as `file` in `.env` file.

So just minor change is required in `.env` file like below:

Replace

```
SESSION_DRIVER=database
```

with

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```